# I'm unable add a lightning page to a changeSet

Tags: change-set, lightning-page

When preparing my changeSet from a sandbox to another one, I can add Static Resources, Apex Classes and Lightning Components BUT
I got this error when trying to add VisualForcePages or a Lightning Page:

> Data Not Available
>   The data you were trying to access could not be found. It may be due to another user deleting the data or a system error. If you know the data is not deleted but cannot access it, please look at our support page.

[image]

The thing is, nothing is wrong with thoses page when I try to access it from SF.

I don't have a clue where to search..

Any ideas ?
Thanks !

EDIT :

As requested, I'm trying this Xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>FlexiPage</name>
    </types>
    <version>36.0</version>
</Package>
```

Migration > Retrieve) returns this XML for the Lightning Page (flexipage) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FlexiPage xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <description>HomePage de l&apos;interface ligthning Heineken.</description>
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentName>MIG_sidebarLiens_HETicketService</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentName>MIG_sideBarCustomLinks</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentName>MIG_sideBarShortcut</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentName>home:recentRecordContainer</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>decorate</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>richTextValue</name>
                <value>&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;https://heineken-fr--miglight.lightning.force.com/lightning/o/DeleteEvent/list&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;Corbeille&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentName>flexipage:richText</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <name>sidebar</name>
        <type>Region</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>context</name>
                <value>BOOKMARKS</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentName>forceChatter:exposedFeed</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <name>Facet-62b46024-b5ed-455d-8782-5a54539db854</name>
        <type>Facet</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>displayNumber</name>
                <value>5</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>recommendationTypes</name>
                <value>[&quot;users&quot;,&quot;groups&quot;]</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>title</name>
                <value>Einstein Recommendations</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentName>forceChatter:recommendations</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <name>Facet-d7a69058-ccfe-4e8c-b7be-3ecae4e9a8ca</name>
        <type>Facet</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>active</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>body</name>
                <value>Facet-62b46024-b5ed-455d-8782-5a54539db854</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>title</name>
                <value>Standard.Tab.collaborate</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentName>flexipage:tab</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>body</name>
                <value>Facet-d7a69058-ccfe-4e8c-b7be-3ecae4e9a8ca</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>title</name>
                <value>Recommandations</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentName>flexipage:tab</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <name>Facet-4b393e6c-999a-4533-baa9-b7670eaefaa0</name>
        <type>Facet</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>tabs</name>
                <value>Facet-4b393e6c-999a-4533-baa9-b7670eaefaa0</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentName>flexipage:tabset</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <name>Facet-82851163-eb7b-42e7-9ab8-ba9fa4723f26</name>
        <type>Facet</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <name>Facet-4d874093-14b0-4734-8606-c0bde5c51bb1</name>
        <type>Facet</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>body</name>
                <value>Facet-82851163-eb7b-42e7-9ab8-ba9fa4723f26</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>label</name>
                <value>Afficher le fil</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>name</name>
                <value>accordionSection1</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentName>flexipage:accordionSection</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>body</name>
                <value>Facet-4d874093-14b0-4734-8606-c0bde5c51bb1</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>label</name>
                <value>Fermer le fil</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>name</name>
                <value>accordionSection--fafnchht45b</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentName>flexipage:accordionSection</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <name>Facet-40dc2cc3-5111-490f-9245-1d13b0c69a8f</name>
        <type>Facet</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentName>MIG_NameAndDay</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>accordionSections</name>
                <value>Facet-40dc2cc3-5111-490f-9245-1d13b0c69a8f</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>defaultSectionName</name>
                <value>accordionSection--fafnchht45b</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentName>flexipage:accordion</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>height</name>
                <value>1200</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>pageName</name>
                <value>MIG_VFP01bis_EIT_CockpitNiv1et2</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>showLabel</name>
                <value>false</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentName>flexipage:visualforcePage</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>height</name>
                <value>830</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>pageName</name>
                <value>MIG_VFP01bis_EIT_Calendar</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>showLabel</name>
                <value>false</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentName>flexipage:visualforcePage</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentName>runtime_approval_process:pendingApprovalCard</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentName>home:eventContainer</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentName>runtime_sales_activities:todayTaskContainer</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>height</name>
                <value>450</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>label</name>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>pageName</name>
                <value>MIG_VFP01_EIT_Cockpit_Accueil</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>showLabel</name>
                <value>false</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentName>flexipage:visualforcePage</componentName>
            <visibilityRule>
                <criteria>
                    <leftValue>{!$User.IsActive}</leftValue>
                    <operator>EQUAL</operator>
                    <rightValue>false</rightValue>
                </criteria>
            </visibilityRule>
        </componentInstances>
        <name>main</name>
        <type>Region</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <masterLabel>MIG_homePage</masterLabel>
    <template>
        <name>MIG_HomeTemplateWithSidebar</name>
    </template>
    <type>HomePage</type>
</FlexiPage>
```

Comment: What does the xml look like if you pull the lightning page in workbench?

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_flexipage.htm

Lightning pages are in the FlexiPage metadata. Taken from their documentation above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>New Opportunity Page Package</fullName>
    <description>Contains an opportunity page with a rich text component that has rules assigned</description>
    <types>
        <members>New_Opportunity_Page</members>
        <name>FlexiPage</name>
    </types>
    <version>41.0</version>
</Package>
```

In change sets, they'd be under "Lightning Page" which I presume you're checking. Either way, it'd be useful to pull the lightning page from workbench to see what it looks like.

Comment: I've edited, can you see womething ? Thanks for your help !

Comment: Are you an admin in terms of permissions to everything it? Also, what's the end-use for this lightning page and VF page?

Comment: Hummm let me tcheck, but I think I have all permissions (yes, I'm admin) ; do you have an idea where specifically I should have a look ? I'm adapting the Classic version of the Saas, to lightning. So I used App Builder and included Visual force pages (yeuk, I know)...

Comment: There's a lot of pieces to it so if you're able in a separate test environment to try stripping away certain components/pieces you could maybe figure out the culprit. What stuck out to me was that you were filtering on one component $User.IsActive = false which I'm not sure makes sense as a visibility rule for the VF page I believe.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your help ! Indeed, I tried without the filtered component (just removed it) and it didn't work. Still the same error, and we discovered we also got this issue with APEX Classes and Buttons... Our team is lost there.

Comment: Then it's probably best to open a support case with Salesforce if you're having issues with all types.

Comment: Well, we're doing it. Thanks anyway for your time & help ;)